# Filtro acusando erro em diferentes campos de senha na mesma view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma VIEW chamada Alterar Senha e nela tenho um campo de Senha Atual, um campo de Nova senha e um campo de Confirmação da Nova senha.

Os três campos passam pelo mesmo filtro de controle para essas senha, cuja regra é que a senha deve ser um campo obrigatório e conter entre 8 e 15 elementos.

Meu problema é: quando o filtro é ativado no primeiro campo de senha (Se a senha não estiver dentro das regras), a mensagem de erro aparece em todos os 3 campos de senha, e não só naquele que está sendo preenchido.

Alguma dica de como isolar esses componentes e fazer com que a mensagem de erro só seja mostrada no campo que não estiver com a informação correta?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-sm-offset-4"><h2>Alterar senha do sistema</h2></div>
</div>
<br>

<div class="container">
    <div class="middle">

<form>

            <!--campo senha atual-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Senha Atual</label>
                        <input asp-for="Password" type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" required>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- nova senha-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <label>Nova Senha</label>
                            <input asp-for="Password" type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Entre 8 e 15 caracteres" required>
                        </div>
                          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
                     </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!--confirmar nova senha-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <label>Confirme a nova senha</label>
                            <input asp-for="Password" type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Entre 8 e 15 caracteres" required>
                        </div>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <br>

            <!--botao salvar-->
            <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-4">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Salvar</button>
            </div>






        </form>

        <!--link cancelar-->
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <a href="#" class="forgot-password">Cancelar</a>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

Esse é o meu filtro para o campo senha

```
    #region Senha
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório")]
        [StringLength(15, MinimumLength = 8, ErrorMessage = "Sua senha deve ter entre 8 e 15 caracteres.")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    #endregion
```

Comment: `mvc` = *padrão de arquitetura* / `asp.net-mvc` = *tecnologia especifica que por acaso se baseia em "mvc"*, então `mvc` != `asp.net-mvc` .......................... por favor quando selecionar as tags leia a descrição de uso correto das mesmas. PS: não use "Trecho de código" (Stack Snippets) sem necessidade, leia: http://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2115/3635. Seja bem vinda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro é que todas os três campos de senha estavam chamando a mesma Validação. No caso, preciso criar três modelos diferentes, um pra Senha Atual, um pra Nova Senha e outro para Confirmação da Nova Senha, e então fazer a chamada dos respectivos modelos para verificação.

MODEL

```
    #region Senha Atual
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório")]
    [StringLength(15, MinimumLength = 8, ErrorMessage = "Sua senha deve ter entre 8 e 15 caracteres.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "SenhaAtual")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Nova Senha
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório")]
    [StringLength(15, MinimumLength = 8, ErrorMessage = "Sua senha deve ter entre 8 e 15 caracteres.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "NovaSenha")]
    public string NewPassword{ get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Confirmar Nova Senha
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório")]
    [StringLength(15, MinimumLength = 8, ErrorMessage = "Sua senha deve ter entre 8 e 15 caracteres.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "ConfirmarNovaSenha")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    #endregion
```

VIEW

```
        <!--campo senha atual-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Senha Atual</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "password" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- nova senha-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Nova Senha</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NewPassword, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "password" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewPassword)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--confirmar nova senha-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Confirme a nova senha</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "password" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```